# Widget Spinner displays list but selecting result will not show

Tags: java, android, xml, widget, spinner

I have a spinner that will start off empty when the activity is opened up. There is also a take a picture button. The picture button opens the camera which works fine and then when it goes back to the activity it makes a call to google vision and grabs descriptions of the object (The descriptions list) which populates the spinner. This all works but when the spinner is opened and something is selected. The spinner doesn't show which object you selected, it just remains empty.

EDIT(I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the spinner being empty when the activity is first created, does anybody know a fix for this??)

The spinner looks like this

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerVisionAPI"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/takePicture"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/takePicture" />
```

My code has these lines in the onCreate

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, descriptions);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerVisionAPI.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinnerVisionAPI.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And here is where it populates the description list

```
    private String formatAnnotation(List<EntityAnnotation> entityAnnotation) {
        String message = "";

        if (entityAnnotation != null) {
            for (EntityAnnotation entity : entityAnnotation) {
                System.out.println(entity.getDescription());
                descriptions.add(entity.getDescription());
//
                message = message + "    " + entity.getDescription() + " " + entity.getScore();
                message += "\n";
            }
        } else {
            message = "Nothing Found";
        }

        return message;
    }
```

Why is it that this box that the spinner has remains empty after something has been selected.

Comment: Do you ever update `ArrayAdapter dataAdapter` with the result of `formatAnnotation`?

Comment: Is the text possibly just blending in with the background? That `android:textColor` attribute you've set won't have an effect on a `Spinner`.

Comment: How would I go about changing this?? I'm very new to android studio

Comment: Also no I never update the Array Adapter, where would be the right place to do this??

Comment: So `ArrayAdapter` has an `add` method, you might want to take a look at that. I.E., `dataAdapter.add(formatAnnotation(...));`.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T)